# Passing username and password to SSRS 2005 reports from web application

Tags: passwords, reporting-services

I want to add security to report(s) based on username and password present in my web application database. But i do not want add parameter(s) username/password in rdl file which shows password in clear text. What is the best way to perform this task? Currently, my reporting server bypass my web service? Report url directly call report on report server. Can I made to pass it via web service which can authenticate user? Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you looking for row based security within your reports or are you trying to pass the credentials from your custom web app to the report server?

Comment: @tnktnk I want to pass the credential from custom web app which are used by my underlying stored procedure..for report server credential I am using **"Credentials stored securely in the report server"** on report manager under data sources..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method that gives you the most flexibility is to override the authentication in SSRS:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152825.aspx

If you're unable or unwilling to go that route, your best option is to pass the username as a report parameter. You should of course make this parameter hidden. In your report database, you will want to create many-to-many security tables that join your user table to the constraining entities in your report queries. For example, if you want row level security by branch or office or department or something, then you'd create a Users_Department table and in your reports query you inner join to that and the users table.

I've done this successfully in a past project. It's doesn't feel very elegant because it requires you to create the property authorization user interface admin screens that fill and update these many-to-many security tables and in addition all of your report queries must join properly to filter to the proper security table to filter the result data sets.

But in some scenario's, it's your best (or only!) option.

Comment: thanks, i think (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152825.aspx) solution is what is the best option in this case, but i will be using the alternate route of adding parameter to each report for simplicity. Thanks!